# C++ - Creating a Spy in unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, ros

I have some C++ code as follows:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(OtherClass *obj)
    {
        obj_ = obj;
    }
    void myMethod()
    {
        // Do something
        int value = obj_->otherMethod();
        // Do something else
    }
private:
    OtherClass *obj_;
}
```

I want to create a unit test to test the functionality of `myMethod()`. Unfortunately, `OtherClass` is an external library and its methods are not declared virtual (so I can't inherit the methods and stub them out in a mock). I have some experience with Mockito where I might have used a spy for this purpose. But I can't seem to find an equivalent in C++.

I'm using the googletest framework for now and the context for this question (if it helps) is in ROS, where I'm actually trying to stub out `tf::TransformListener`.

**Question 1:** Is there an alternative to spies that I might not know of and can leverage in this situation?

**Question 2:** If there isn't, is there a *quick-and-easy* way for me to restructure my code so that I can leverage a mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by doing the following:

```
class IOtherMethodAdapter
{
public:
    virtual int otherMethod() = 0;
}

class OtherClassOtherMethodAdapter : public IOtherMethodAdapter
{
public:
    int otherMethod() { return obj_->otherMethod(); }
private:
    OtherClass *obj_;
}
```

Now I use a pointer to `IOtherMethodAdapter` in `MyClass` instead of `OtherClass` and for testing I simply initialize the implementation of the interface to a stubbed/mock object. If there is another way, feel free to post that solution too.